# Json parsing Swift

Tags: json, swift, parsing

I'm pretty new in Swift. I want to fetch following three values from the Json object. This Json is optional whenever I try to fetch any value, It doesn't print anything. What is the right way to get required data ?

```
            data : Optional((
                    {
                    position =         {
                        x = "0.45625";
                        y = "0.725";
                    };
                    user =         {
                        "full_name" = "Dubai TV \U0642\U0646\U0627\U0629 \U062f\U0628\U064a";
                        id = 220343467;
                        "profile_picture" = "";
                        username = dubaitv;
                    };
                },
                    {
                    position =         {
                        x = "0.7890625";
                        y = "0.590625";
                    };
                    user =         {
                        "full_name" = "U.S. Soccer";
                        id = 226991466;
                        "profile_picture" = "";
                        username = ussoccer;
                    };
                },
                    {
                    position =         {
                        x = "0.6234375";
                        y = "0.496875";
                    };
                    user =         {
                        "full_name" = "";
                        id = 1379193902;
                        "profile_picture" = "";
                        username = "dubai_360";
                    };
                }
            ))
```

The following code I'm using to fetch data:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, path, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { response in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                if response.result.isSuccess {
                    if let json = response.result.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                        if let data = json["data"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
                            let (mediaItem, _) = MediaItem.mediaItemWithData(data, forUser: user)

                            if mediaItem != nil {
                                success?(mediaItem: mediaItem!)
                                return
                            }
```

I need to get following data from Json object
             username = dubaitv
             username = ussoccer
             username = dubai_360

Comment: Can you describe more on your code and Please try : http://roadfiresoftware.com/2015/10/how-to-parse-json-with-swift-2/

Comment: can you please put your code ...

Comment: I'm making API call to get this Json object.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I'd try this link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very easy to get value from JSON in Swift. I used following code to get required values from JSON.

```
if let taggedUsers = data["users_in_photo"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
   if let userName = user["username"] as? String {
       print(userName)
   }
}
```